# ASP.NET Core test method with DisableRequestSizeLimit

Tags: c#, testing, asp.net-core, httprequest, integration-testing

I have an ASP.NET Core project, with this method:

```cs
public async Task<ActionResult<ResultDto>> StartReadFiles(
    [ModelBinder(typeof(JsonModelBinder))] RequestDto request,
    IFormFile file1,
    IFormFile file2
)
```

After I pushed the method, the *performance test* failed because he sends very large files in the request.

So I added `DisableRequestSizeLimit` to the method:

```cs
[DisableRequestSizeLimit]
public async Task<ActionResult<ResultDto>> StartReadFiles(
    [ModelBinder(typeof(JsonModelBinder))] RequestDto request,
    IFormFile file1,
    IFormFile file2
)
```

And now, I want to write a test for this bug.

**How can I fake the request with a very big body?**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is very convenient to write such tests using [RestSharp](http://restsharp.org/) nuget package. Your tests will make real http-requests to your `Asp.net core` app:

```
var client = new RestClient("http://path/to/api/");

var request = new RestRequest("resourceurl", Method.POST);

byte[] fileByteArray = new byte[50*1024*1024]; // 50 MB
request.AddFileBytes("file1", fileByteArray, "file1Name"); 

// execute the request
IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
var content = response.Content; // raw content as string
```

Btw, by default asp.net core app [has](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/file-uploads?view=aspnetcore-2.1#troubleshooting) 28.6 MB request size limit. You can disable it by `[DisableRequestSizeLimit]` (as you did) and then you can make request with any payload size, but it is usually an undesired behavior. Then, probably it is better to use `[RequestSizeLimit(50_000_000)]` to change the default limit to a desired value.

Comment: Why using `[RequestSizeLimit(50_000_000)]` instead of `[DisableRequestSizeLimit]` is increasing the request size? There is a default or something?

Comment: yes, by default asp.net core [has](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/file-uploads?view=aspnetcore-2.1#troubleshooting) a limit 30 000 000 bytes, which is approximately 28.6MB

Comment: So if I set `[DisableRequestSizeLimit]`, it's actually set the size limit to the default?

Comment: no. By default asp.net core app has 28.6 MB request size limit.  You can disable it by  `[DisableRequestSizeLimit]` and then you can make request with any payload size, but it is usually an undesired behavior. `[RequestSizeLimit(50_000_000)]` allows to configure that limit.

Comment: From your answer I might understand that `RequestSizeLimit` increase the allowed size of `DisableRequestSizeLimit`

Answer (score 4):

Maybe you are not hitting the request size limit but the form size limit; please try with `RequestFormLimits(MultipartBodyLengthLimit=Int32.MaxValue)`.
Please note `MultipartBodyLengthLimit` is of long type and considering your case I think it is fair enough to full fill form size limit.

Comment: I don't think that's an answer to the question.

Comment: But today it is!